# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Compilation cannot be undefined after updating to Angular 15 from 14

Tags: testing, karma-coverage

After migration to angular 15,
I started getting this error.
With angular 14 it's working fine with no issues

Checked path for styles under test.styles in angular.json but no luck

Also tried other approaches from different stack overflow answers but no luck